# Using MaskedEditExtender results in runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am struggling with using the AJAX Control Toolkit in my ASP.NET code.

I downloaded and imported the dll files from the website and try to follow the instructions,...

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
```

... inserted a Script Manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and put the ajax MaskEditExtender under the text box that I want to check on:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ind_customerRevenue" MaxLength="20" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
    CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
    CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
    CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" 
    Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="ind_customerRevenue">
</ajaxtoolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
```

But when I debug the side it says:

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys.Extended.UI' is null or not an object

What am I missing out? I cannot find an answer somehow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToolkitScriptManager instead of the default ScriptManager.

replace

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

with

```html
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```